# Inline display not working with canvas element

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas and a side `div` and I am using `display:inline-block;` to display them side by side. But it is not working. The side div has some empty space on the top. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5yezcxt/9/).
I know I can achieve it by giving `absolute` position, but it would great if someone could help me understand why this is wrong.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainDiv" >
    <div class="sidebarDiv" >
    HEY
    </div>
    <div class="canvasDiv">
        <canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainDiv{
  height: 100vh;
}
.canvasDiv{
    width: calc(100% - 75px);
   display: inline-block;
}

.sidebarDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas {

    background: blue;;
    width:  inherit;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: please check the duplicate, because the answer you accpeted has nothing to do with inline-block and is not fixing your issue, it's simply using float

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `float: left` in your `inline-block` divs.

```css
.mainDiv{
  height: 100vh;
}

.canvasDiv{
  float: left;
 width: calc(100% - 75px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebarDiv{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas {
 background: blue;;
 width:  inherit;
 height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainDiv" >
  <div class="sidebarDiv" >
    HEY
  </div>
  <div class="canvasDiv">
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Important note: the use of float make the inline-block useless as the element will a become a block level element